# Preventing swipe from recent apps to terminate tcp connection in a foreground service

Tags: java, android, sockets, service, tcp

I am using a foreground service to perform long I/O operations (upload of files) with a server via a tcp socket.

Inside the service I am using an AsynTask to be able to publish the transfer progress to the UI (notification or whatever else, I don't really mind).

The problem is whenever the app is swiped from recent apps, the socket seems to get closed as well. This is completely contradictory to everything I have read and tested regarding foreground services (like the music app when I swipe it, it displays a foreground service notification and music keeps playing without a glitch).

So what am I doing wrong?

here is my service code:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Log.i(TAG, "StorageServerProxyService started");

    final Intent intentForThread = intent;

    new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (intentForThread != null)
            {
                String action = intentForThread.getAction();
                Log.i(TAG, "Action:" + action);

                PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);

                try {
                    connectIfNecessary();

                    switch (action) {

                        case ACTION_UPLOAD: {
                            startServiceForeground();
                            wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG + "_wakeLock");
                            wakeLock.acquire();
                            String destId = intentForThread.getStringExtra(DESTINATION_ID);
                            FileManager managedFile = (FileManager) intentForThread.getSerializableExtra(FILE_TO_UPLOAD);
                            uploadFileToServer(destId, managedFile);
                            releaseLockIfNecessary();
                            stopForeground(true);
                        }
                        break;

                        default:
                            Log.w(TAG, "Service started with action:" + action);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    String errMsg = "Action failed:"+action+" Exception:"+e.getMessage();
                    Log.e(TAG, errMsg);
                    handleDisconnection(errMsg);
                }
            } else
                Log.w(TAG, "Service started with missing action");


        }
    }.start();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

public void uploadFileToServer(final String destNumber, final FileManager managedFile) throws IOException {

    TransferDetails td = new TransferDetails(SharedConstants.MY_ID, destNumber, managedFile);
    new UploadTask(getApplicationContext(), connectionToServer).execute(td);
}

private void startServiceForeground() {

    Notification notification = new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_upload, getText(R.string.upload_ticker_text),
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, StorageServerProxyService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
            getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
    startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

This is the AsynTask (UploadTask) code:

```
public class UploadTask extends AsyncTask<TransferDetails,String,Void> {
private NotificationHelper mNotificationHelper;
private static final String TAG = UploadTask.class.getSimpleName();
private ConnectionToServer _connectionToServer;
private TransferDetails _td;
private Context _context;

public UploadTask(Context context, ConnectionToServer connectionToServer){
    _context = context;
    mNotificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(_context);
    _connectionToServer = connectionToServer;
}

protected void onPreExecute(){
    //Create the notification in the statusbar
    mNotificationHelper.createUploadNotification();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(TransferDetails... details) {

    _td = details[0];
    FileManager managedFile = _td.get_managedFile();
    MessageUploadFile msgUF = new MessageUploadFile(_td.getSourceId(),_td);

    try {
        _connectionToServer.sendToServer(msgUF);


        Log.i(TAG, "Initiating file data upload...");

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(_connectionToServer.getClientSocket().getOutputStream());

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(managedFile.getFile());
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 8];
        long fileSize = managedFile.getFileSize();
        long bytesToRead = fileSize;
        int bytesRead;
        while (bytesToRead > 0 && (bytesRead = bis.read(buf, 0, (int) Math.min(buf.length, bytesToRead))) != -1) {
            dos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            String msg = "File upload to:"+_td.getDestinationId()+" %.0f%% complete";
            float percent = (float) (fileSize - bytesToRead) / fileSize * 100;
            publishProgress(String.format(msg, percent));
            bytesToRead -= bytesRead;
        }
    }
     catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed:" + e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    //This method runs on the UI thread, it receives progress updates
    //from the background thread and publishes them to the status bar
    mNotificationHelper.progressUpdate(progress[0]);
}
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)    {
    //The task is complete, tell the status bar about it
    mNotificationHelper.completed();
}

}
```

Comment: when i play music and then swipe the app from my recents list the music stops playing and that is the expected behavior

Comment: Not if you use a foreground service to play the music. This is the exact purpose of a foreground service, and you can verify that by using the native music app which uses a foreground service when music is playing and the app is swiped. 

Please anyone with something helpful to say?

Comment: I did verify it by using the Google music app like I said and it stopped playing music like it should. Removing the app from the recent list essentially kills the entire app

Comment: Maybe the difference is due to different versions? I am testing it using Galaxy S3 running on Android 4.3 and it positively doesn't stop the music. Did the behavior of foreground services change since then? And even if it did, still doesn't explain why it stops the tcp connection in my foreground service but not the music in their foreground service :) Because I am testing my service on the same device.